# Macros in MathJaX

Tags: mathjax

I would like to add some macros in my MathJax configuration. Specifically I would like to add:

- `\arcsin` and be displayed as `{\rm arcsin}`
- `\arccos` and be displayed as `{\rm arccos}`
- `\arctan` and be displayed as `{\rm arctan}`
- `\arccot` and be displayed as `{\rm arccot}`

I have read the MathJaX documentation and although I think that I do the steps right, I end up with either the MathJaX not working properly or not loaded at all. By the way, why are these commands not supported at all? I think they should. Is there a specific reason?

How can I add these macros in my configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MathJax 3 [supports all the commands](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/macros/index.html) you mentioned (`\arcsin`, `\arccos`, `\arctan` and `\arccot`) so you don't have to create macros for them. For `\arccot`, the [`physics` extension](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/physics.html) must be loaded.